# Setting up Bluetooth GATT and BLE and using UUIDs

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, uuid, gatt

I am trying to connect an Ardiuno to an Android Smartphone via GATT profile. After looking at several tutorials and the Android documentation I have more questions than answers...
[On this tutorial](http://toastdroid.com/2014/09/22/android-bluetooth-low-energy-tutorial/) the author says after implementing the device discovery with "BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback" there should be a device. The implementation for "onLeScan" is missing and I have absolutely no idea what to put in there and how to access the BluetoothDevice he talks about. The device is not a return value but an initial value for this method, so how do I get it?

Another quite basic (and rather dumb) question is where to put all this BLE stuff in my code? It seems that part of it needs to be in an activity to work, but I already have classes for making SPP Bluetooth connections and I would like to merge these two together. So how do I achieve this as easy as possible?

Last but not least: does anyone know an easy example of the usage of Bluetooth GATT profile for API Level 18 which could light up my situation a little bit?

I am sorry for asking something so basic and I guess I just don't know enough about programming to understand all of this, but the tutorials I found really didn't help much...I am happy to read all of your comments.

I nearly have it running, though I am still having issues with the UUIDS.
I figured the `uuidList` in point 5 should be what I know about the device I want to connect. So I defined it like this in my main activity:

```
String[] uuids={"6e400001-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e","6e400002-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e","6e400003-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e","00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"
        ,"E20A39F4-73F5-4BC4-A12F-17D1AD07A961","08590F7E-DB05-467E-8757-72F6FAEB13D4","08590F7F-DB05-467E-8757-72F6FAEB13D4"};
```

because of these parts in the GATT programm for my LinkIt One I want to connect:

```
    static LGATTServiceInfo g_uart_decl[] =
{
    {TYPE_SERVICE, "E20A39F4-73F5-4BC4-A12F-17D1AD07A961", TRUE, 0, 0, 0},
    {TYPE_CHARACTERISTIC, "08590F7E-DB05-467E-8757-72F6FAEB13D4", FALSE, VM_GATT_CHAR_PROP_NOTIFY | VM_GATT_CHAR_PROP_READ, VM_GATT_PERM_READ, 0}, // tx for periphral; rx for central
    {TYPE_CHARACTERISTIC, "08590F7F-DB05-467E-8757-72F6FAEB13D4", FALSE, VM_GATT_CHAR_PROP_WRITE, VM_GATT_PERM_WRITE, 0}, // rx for periphral; tx for central
    {TYPE_END, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}

};
```

and

```
static LGATTServiceInfo g_abc_decl[] =
{
    {TYPE_SERVICE, "6e400001-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e", TRUE, 0, 0, 0},
    {TYPE_CHARACTERISTIC, "6e400002-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e", FALSE, VM_GATT_CHAR_PROP_WRITE, VM_GATT_PERM_WRITE, 0},
    {TYPE_CHARACTERISTIC, "6e400003-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e", FALSE, VM_GATT_CHAR_PROP_NOTIFY | VM_GATT_CHAR_PROP_INDICATE, VM_GATT_PERM_READ, 0},
    {TYPE_DESCRIPTOR, "00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", FALSE, VM_GATT_CHAR_PROP_NOTIFY, VM_GATT_PERM_READ | VM_GATT_PERM_WRITE, 0},
    {TYPE_END, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
};
```

I call the scanning method like this in my main class:

```
final GpsBoxScanningFactory scanningFactory=new GpsBoxScanningFactory();
        scanningFactory.startScanning("LinkIt One",uuids);
        final Handler handler=new  Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                List<GpsBoxBluetoothDevice> leBtDeviceList=scanningFactory.getFoundDeviceList();
                scanningFactory.stopScanning();
            }
        },5000);
```

Note that I declare `scanningFactory` final because the documentation said so...If this is not how it's done then I am glad to change that.

The problem is, that every time I scan for devices the `leBtDeviceList` is of size 0, though the LinkIt One (something like an Arduino but with different chip and Bluetooth on board) is running and paired.
I guess this is because I use the uuids wrongly, could someone please explain what to put in `uuidList` and the part where I now put `"LinkItOne"`?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/2462/bluetooth-and-bluetooth-le-api#t=201610061257567451853

Comment: Thank you @antonio , that helped a lot.